# Verify that field is set in struct golang

Tags: go

I have the following struct:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar *FooBar
    Baz *FooBaz
}

type FooBar struct {
    Name string
}

type FooBaz struct {
    Name string
}
```

How can I access the `Baz` and `Bar` in the struct without getting a nil pointer reference when they're not set?

I want something that goes like the below, but I keep getting nil pointer dereference errors.

```
if Foo.Bar == nil {
  throw error
}
```

I'm struggling with this!

Comment: comparing it to `nil` is precisely what you do. Can you show an example that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @noqcks The error for nil pointer always comes when you are passing a nil value in place where it is required to have some value assigned. Post the code in which you are getting an error of nil pointer

Comment: Are you making sure Foo isn't nil?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to compare to nil, here's a working example:

```
check := func(f Foo) {
  if f.Bar == nil {
    panic("oops!")
  }
  fmt.Println("OK")
}

foo1 := Foo{Bar: &FooBar{"Alpha"}}
check(foo1) // OK

foo2 := Foo{}
check(foo2) // panic: oops!
```

Note that if you were to modify the "check" function to accept a `*Foo` and it was called with a nil pointer then that function would itself panic with a "nil pointer dereference runtime error". This might be what is currently happening with your example.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have any errors thrown when attempting to access a nil member of the Foo struct.  Here is a [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/axUBar3nzYQ) where the program exits without error.

However, if you want to guarantee Bar and Baz is always set, I'd recommend making a function for building your Foo struct and making the Bar and Biz members lowercase as to not be visible by external packages:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
    bar *FooBar
    baz *FooBaz

}

type FooBar struct {
    Name string
}

type FooBaz struct {
    Name string
}

func NewFoo(bar *FooBar, baz *FooBaz) *Foo {

    r := &Foo {bar, baz}

    if bar == nil {
        r.bar = &FooBar{"default bar"}
    }

    if baz == nil {
        r.baz = &FooBaz{"default baz"}
    }

    return r
}

func main() {
    f := NewFoo(nil, nil)

    // prints: f.Bar: default bar
    fmt.Printf("f.Bar: %v", f.bar.Name)
}
```